# What happens if you go out playing a wild and then flip over wild in Mario Kart Uno?

Tags: uno-mario-kart

What happens if you go out playing a wild/item box and then flip over another wild/item box in Mario Kart Uno? Do you win or do you have to draw 2 and stay in? See image of card in question.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean playing an item box and revealing the bom-omb?

Comment: Yes.  see edit with card in question